# M2Crypto segmentation fault in verifying sign

Tags: python, cryptography, digital-signature, m2crypto

I'm trying to add a sign field to a json request before submit and verify it in response. What I do is I load key pair once in initialization then (according [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Snegovikufa/5232301)) use following methods inside my class:

```
import M2Crypto

class MyRequestHandler:

    SIGN_PRIVATE = M2Crypto.EVP.load_key('/path/to/signing/key')
    SIGN_PUBLIC = M2Crypto.RSA.load_pub_key('/path/to/verification/key')

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    # signing
    @classmethod
    def sign(cls, data):
        cls.SIGN_PRIVATE.sign_init()
        cls.SIGN_PRIVATE.sign_update(data)
        signed_data = cls.SIGN_PRIVATE.sign_final()
        signed_data_base64 = signed_data.encode('base64')
        return signed_data_base64

    # verifying
    @classmethod
    def verify(cls, response):
        signature = response['sign'].decode('base64')
        data = response['data']
        verify_evp = M2Crypto.EVP.PKey()
        verify_evp.assign_rsa(cls.SIGN_PUBLIC)
        verify_evp.verify_init()
        verify_evp.verify_update(data)
        return verify_evp.verify_final(signature) == 1
```

The problem is `verify` works fine when called once, but calling it again results in a segmentation fault no matter what is the data and signature. Why is this happening? And generally am I doing the process the right way?

**Edit**: to reproduce the problem in a python shell using public key extracted from private key used in signing (consider we want to verify our own sign):

```
data = "test message"
signature = MeyRequestHandler.sign(data)
res = {"data": data, "sign": signature}
MyRequestHandler.verify(res)  # works fine
MyRequestHandler.verify(res)  # segmentation fault in *verify_final*
```

M2Crypto version is `0.25.1`.

Comment: Exactly what statement in `verify()` is causing the segfault?

Comment: @martineau it's the last line, `verify_final`

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't show how `cls.SIGN_PRIVATE` is created/initialized, and that seems relevant. Try to create a [_Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) illustrating the problem and put it in your question.

Comment: Reproducer is in https://gitlab.com/mcepl/m2crypto/commit/906d0707cb7cec9265c7c34e16583884b9ede86b and the issue is being resolved in https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/merge_requests/101